# Narasimhan-Seshadri and Weil's theorem

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, holomorphic-bundles

I am trying to make sense of how the following two statements fit together. Here, $X$ is a compact Riemann surface and $E$ is a holomorphic vector bundle of rank $r$ over $X$.

Theorem 1 (Weil): Let $E$ be indecomposable. Then, deg($E$) = 0 if and only if $E$ arises from a representation $\rho: \pi_1(X) \rightarrow GL(r, \mathbb{C})$.

Theorem 2 (Narasimhan-Seshadri): A degree 0 vector bundle is stable if and only if $E$ arises from an irreducible representation $\rho: \pi_1(X) \rightarrow U(r)$.

Can I view Theorem 2 as a ``restriction" of Theorem 1? I have a feeling that it would be naive to do so because Weil's theorem does not say that a representation $\rho: \pi_1(X) \rightarrow GL(r, \mathbb{C})$ defines an indecomposable, degree 0 vector bundles.

Edit: Furthermore, perhaps one can't view Theorem 2 as a ``restriction" of Theorem 1 because Weil hasn't proved that two degree 0 vector bundles are biholomorphic if and only if their corresponding representations are equivalent. I think the picture we get from these two theorems is but I could be wrong.

[image: Weil and Narasimhan-Seshadri's theorems]

Comment: These are independent results;Theorem 2 is harder.